# Can't get data_uri working in mongoid-grid_fs gem

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, gridfs

I have images stored in the fs.files and fs.chunks collections in the Mongodb and would like to render those images on a site that I built with Ruby on Rails.

I have installed the mongoid-grid_fs gem (https://github.com/ahoward/mongoid-grid_fs) and mongoid gem (4.0.0) and tried to test it on the rails console but the data uris of the images do not seem to be working.

```
f = Mongoid::GridFs.get('551dd9bde4b0adc8adcebc27')
=> #<Mongoid::GridFs::Fs::File _id: 551dd9bde4b0adc8adcebc27, length: 1793437, chunkSize: 261120, uploadDate: 2015-04-03 00:07:25 UTC, md5: "4deeaab5116771bc838d522b63712423", filename: "f54f40db-50a6-474d-9310-bd42fd44dab5", contentType: "application/octet-stream", aliases: nil, metadata: {"_id"=>"f54f40db-50a6-474d-9310-bd42fd44dab5", "media_id"=>"e916e264-61a9-4d69-8b70-4834cbcae75e", "size"=>1793437, "content_type"=>"application/octet-stream"}> 
f.data_uri
=> "data:application/octet-stream;base64,IzxNb25nb2lkOjpHcmlkRnM6OkZzOjpGaWxlOjB4MDAwMDAwMDQ1OGQ1Mjg+"
```

Then when I pasted the data uri on the browser, a file was downloaded. When I opened it, there is only a line like below.

```
"#<Mongoid::GridFs::Fs::File:0x0000000458d528>"
```

When I went back to the console using decode64 for the data uri, the same line appeared.

```
Base64.decode64('IzxNb25nb2lkOjpHcmlkRnM6OkZzOjpGaWxlOjB4MDAwMDAwMDQ1OGQ1Mjg+')
=>"#<Mongoid::GridFs::Fs::File:0x0000000458d528>"
```

I am not very familiar with Mongodb and would like to know how I could possibly get  the working data uris for the images. Any help is appreciated and thank you very much~!